# Java Mockito with RestTemplate.exchange using Generics

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a generic method which invokes specified URL using `RestTemplate.exchange`. Method itself is working and loading data fine but I am not able to unit test it using Mockito.

**Main Method**

```
@Service
public class MyClass{
    private <T> List<T> loadData(String url) {
        return restTemplate.exchange(
            url, GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>(){}
        ).getBody().stream().collect(toList()));
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@Runwith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void givenCall_myMethod_WillReturnData(){
        given(restTemplate.exchange(
            ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(), any(), any(Class.class)
        ))
        .willReturn(bodyData());
    }
}
```

If I use non-generic version then everything works fine, however mockito returns `NullPointerException` with generics version.

What's wrong or missing?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? "If I use non-generic version" show us

Comment: Also your class only has one private method and your test doesn't test anything. Looks like you've removed too many details, to the point where this no longer makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Michael. This site is only available in read-only mode in my firm so I have been trying to type everything on the mobile phone hence couldn't provide much details :)

Comment: `RestOperations` exists for a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last wildcard you have defined as: `any(Class.class)`.

The exchange method has signature:

```
exchange(String url,
             HttpMethod method,
             HttpEntity<?> requestEntity,
             ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) throws RestClientException
```

You should define it as: `any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class)`

Also I would suggest replacing the very vague `any()` set-us with a `any(Class)` equivalents.

Comment: Thanks @Maciej. You are right, I should be using: any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class). instead of Class.class.